# Define Java for wsimport

Tags: java, wsimport

I'm trying to build java classes with wsimport which will be packed into a jar which will be usable on servers running 1.6. I am running 1.7. I am encountering a version error because I assume wsimport is using 1.7 to build the classes. I do have 1.6 on my machine, is there a way I can force wsimport to run with 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently wsimport comes as part of the JDK suite. So I just included the full path the version of wsimport I wanted.

Thanks,